# divs inside div are displayed below?

Tags: html, css

I have 4 small div's inside another div. Somehow instead of displaying the small ones inside, they are displayed below!

I tried to Google it after playing around and not solving it. Seems to be so simple but I could not find anything related.

https://jsfiddle.net/j4pnh0rz/

This is how it show right now:

```
______________________________________________
| Mat                                         |
______________________________________________|
    ________   ________   ________   ________ 
   |       |  |       |  |       |  |       |
   |   B   |  |   C   |  |   A   |  |   M   |
   |_______|  |_______|  |_______|  |_______|
```

This is how it **should** be:

```
______________________________________________
| Mat                                         |
|   ________   ________   ________   ________ |
|  |       |  |       |  |       |  |       | |
|  |   B   |  |   C   |  |   A   |  |   M   | |
|  |_______|  |_______|  |_______|  |_______| |
______________________________________________|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to change the display rule for the divs:

https://jsfiddle.net/j4pnh0rz/1/

```
div {
    display: inline-block; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

immediately after

```
<div class="mat green">
  <p class="symbol">M</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your div is set to `display: block;`

Change it to `display: inline-block`

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;
}
div {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.inner {
  width: 94%;
  margin: 0 2%;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(153, 153, 153, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(153, 153, 153, 0.75);
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(153, 153, 153, 0.75);
  padding: 5px;
}
div.main {
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  width: 35%;
  max-width: 350px;
  min-width: 238px;
  float: left;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  div.main {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 560px;
    min-width: 350px;
    float: none;
  }
}
div.mat {
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  width: 22%;
  padding: 1%;
}
div.green {
  background-color: #77bb77;
  border: 1px solid #559955;
}
div.yellow {
  background-color: #bbbb77;
  border: 1px solid #999955;
}
div.red {
  background-color: #bb7777;
  border: 1px solid #995555;
}
p {
  font-size: 13pt;
  color: #222;
  margin: 0.5em;
}
.lead {
  font-size: 15pt;
  color: #111;
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
}
.small {
  font-size: 10pt;
  color: #222;
}
.symbol {
  margin: 0 !important;
  font-size: 20pt;
  color: #111;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="inner">
    <p class="lead">Mat <span class="small"><a href="#">view more</a></span>
    </p>
    <div class="mat green">
      <p class="symbol">B</p>
    </div>
    <div class="mat yellow">
      <p class="symbol">C</p>
    </div>
    <div class="mat red">
      <p class="symbol">A</p>
    </div>
    <div class="mat green">
      <p class="symbol">M</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `clearfix`

```
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    display: table;
    line-height: 0;
    content: "";
}
.clearfix {
    *zoom: 1;
}
.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}
```

add class `clearfix` for `inner`

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;
}


.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
 display: table;
 line-height: 0;
 content: "";
}
.clearfix {
 *zoom: 1;
}
.clearfix:after {
 clear: both;
}

div {
    display:block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
.inner {
    width: 94%;
    margin: 0 2%;   
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(153, 153, 153, 0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(153, 153, 153, 0.75);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(153, 153, 153, 0.75);
}
div.main {
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    width: 35%;
    max-width: 350px;
    min-width: 238px;
    float: left;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    div.main {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 80%;
        max-width: 560px;
        min-width: 350px;
        float:none;
    }
}
div.mat {
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    width: 22%;
    padding: 1%;
}
div.green {
    background-color: #77bb77;
    border: 1px solid #559955;
}
div.yellow {
    background-color: #bbbb77;
    border: 1px solid #999955;
}
div.red {
    background-color: #bb7777;
    border: 1px solid #995555;
}
p {
    font-size: 13pt;
    color: #222;
    margin: 0.5em;
}
.lead {
    font-size: 15pt;
    color: #111;
    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
}
.small {
    font-size: 10pt;
    color: #222;
}
.symbol {
    margin: 0 !important;
    font-size: 20pt;
    color: #111;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <div class="inner clearfix">
        <p class="lead">Mat <span class="small"><a href="#">view more</a></span>
        </p>
        <div class="mat green">
            <p class="symbol">B</p>
        </div>
        <div class="mat yellow">
            <p class="symbol">C</p>
        </div>
        <div class="mat red">
            <p class="symbol">A</p>
        </div>
        <div class="mat green">
            <p class="symbol">M</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/j4pnh0rz/3/)

You just need to change `display:block` to `display:inline-block` for `div`